# How to set the compiler encoding?

Tags: java, maven

I'd like to make Maven compile my project with the -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 flag, by setting it in the pom.xml, of the parent project.

This is not doing it:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

So I get this error when Maven compiles:

```
    javac option: M:\Parent\persistence\target\generated-sources\apt
...\Database.java:90: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
     * Semantics of SQL INSERT OR IGNOREÃ?
```

Comment: May we see the incriminated line in Database.java, just for completeness?

Comment: It looks the Database.java is a generated file and may be you missed to configure the correct at the plugin ? which generated the Database.java file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, what you have looks to be correct:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

since that's failing, try setting it explicitly:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: See the docs: Default value is: ${project.build.sourceEncoding}.

Comment: even doing so (and even <ecoding>UTF-8</encoding> did sovle the problem. I'm setting only the parent pom. Maybe if I change in the project pom it will work.